# java.lang.IllegalStateException when collecting flow from SqlDelight in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, sqldelight

I am trying to use SqlDelight database in my app.

In my DAO, I have a function called getRecipeById to query the database and return a flow of domain model (Recipe). Here is the implementation of the function: (Note: RecipeTable is the name of the table, or I guess I should have called it RecipeEntity)

```
fun getRecipeById(id: Int): Flow<Recipe> {
    return recipeQueries.getRecipeById(id)
        .asFlow()
        .mapToOne()
        .map { recipeTable: RecipeTable ->
            recipeTableToRecipeMapper(recipeTable = recipeTable)
        }
}
```

Then my repository calls this function like this: (Note: recipeLocalDatabase is my DAO)

```
suspend fun getRecipeById(id: Int): Flow<RecipeDTO> {
    val recipeFromDB: Flow<Recipe> = recipeLocalDatabase.getRecipeById(id)
    return recipeFromDB.map { recipe: Recipe ->
        recipeDTOMapper.mapDomainModelToDTO(recipe)
    }
}
```

Then my usecase layer calls the function from repository and pass along the flow:

```
suspend fun execute(
    id: Int
): UseCaseResult<Flow<RecipeDTO>>
{
    return try{
        UseCaseResult.Success(recipeRepository.getRecipeById(id))
    } catch(exception: Exception){
        UseCaseResult.Error(exception)
    }
}
```

Now within the ViewModel, I am collecting the flow of RecipeDTO like this:

```
var recipeForDetailView: MutableState<RecipeDTO> = mutableStateOf(
    RecipeDTO(
        id  = 0,
        title = "",
        featuredImage = "",
        ingredients = listOf()
    )
)

fun onLaunch(recipeId: Int){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        when(val result = getRecipeDetailUseCase.execute(recipeId))
        {
            is UseCaseResult.Success ->
                 result.resultValue.collect{ recipeDTO: RecipeDTO ->
                     recipeForDetailView.value = recipeDTO
                 }
            is UseCaseResult.Error -> Log.d("Debug: RecipeDetailViewModel",
                result.exception.toString()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My View layer will then observe the MutableState object.
Now, I keep getting this error every once a while

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
Process: com.noat.recipe_food2fork, PID: 13923
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.readError(Snapshot.kt:1530)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.current(Snapshot.kt:1770)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutableStateImpl.setValue(SnapshotState.kt:891)
    at com.noat.recipe_food2fork.ui.viewModel.RecipeDetailViewModel$onLaunch$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:133)
    at com.noat.recipe_food2fork.data.repositoryImplementation.recipeRepository.RecipeRepository$getRecipeById$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:135)
    at com.noat.recipe_food2fork.data.local.RecipeLocalDatabase$getRecipeById$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:135)
    at com.squareup.sqldelight.runtime.coroutines.FlowQuery$mapToOne$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:135)
    at com.squareup.sqldelight.runtime.coroutines.FlowQuery$mapToOne$$inlined$map$1$2$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

I think it is the flow collecting that caused the error, or maybe because of the fact that I am using MutableState? Googling the error does not help much... Does anyone know what is the cause of this issue? Thank you! Sorry for the long long post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `MutableState` is designed to be used in the ViewModel layer, since it's an observable integrated with the compose runtime.
You could create a `MutableStateFlow` instead and use `collectAsState()` from the view layer.

In your case the issue is probably, because of the state is captured in a coroutine invoked outside composition.

Comment: Thank You @Robert Nagy

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Robert Nagy. Set the mutable state value in Dispatchers.Main context or use MutableStateFlow in viewmodel and use collectAsState() in composable function.

```
private fun getExpenseAddData() {
    _expenseAddState.value = ExpenseAddState(isLoading = true)
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val expenseAddState = try {
            val categoryListDto = repository.getAllCategories()
            val paymentTypeListDto = repository.getAllPaymentType()
            if (categoryListDto.isNullOrEmpty() || paymentTypeListDto.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                ExpenseAddState(error = "Error retrieving expense category or payment type")
            } else {
                ExpenseAddState(expenseAddData = ExpenseAddData(
                    categoryList = categoryListDto.map { it.toExpenseCategory() },
                    paymentTypeList = paymentTypeListDto.map { it.toPaymentType() }
                ))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ExpenseAddState(error = e.message
                ?: "Error retrieving expense category or payment type")
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            _expenseAddState.value = expenseAddState
        }
    }
}
```